# bolt CMS not routing to singular page of contenttype?

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I have a contenttype called textimonials in my `contenttypes.yml` file, like so:

```
#Testimonials
testimonials:
    name: Testimonials
    singular_name: Testimonial
    fields:
        name:
            type: text
            class: large
        position:
            type: text
        body:
            type: textarea
            height: 150px
    listing_template: testimonials.twig
    record_template: testimonial.twig
```

Now the documentation says the following:

> Whenever your browser gets a page on a Bolt website, it uses an URL
>   like /entries or /page/lorem-ipsum. Bolt knows how to handle URLs like
>   these, and displays the information the browser requested. Bolt does
>   this by mapping the URL to a so-called Route. This Route is the
>   controller that (when called) fetches the content from the database,
>   selects the template to use, renders the HTML page according to that
>   template and the content and serves it to the browser.
>
> At the same time, if you create a new record, Bolt will know what the
>   URL for that content is. So when that URL is requested by a browser,
>   it can map it back to the correct content.
>
> For example, if you have a ‘Pages’ contenttype, with ‘Page’ as a
>   singular_name, your site will automatically have pages like:

```
http://example.org/pages
http://example.org/page/lorem-ipsum-dolor
```

Well i have bolt installed on localhost , so now when i navigate to `http://localhost:8080/boltCMS/testimonials` , i see my testimonials.twig , but when i navigate to `http://localhost:8080/boltCMS/testimonials/1` , i get a error of :

> Page testimonials/1 not found.

Why ? my database is populated , so why am i getting this error ?

The templates and routes documentation can be found **[HERE](https://docs.bolt.cm/templates-routes)**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a `singular_slug` setting for a contenttype.

Bolt tries to automatically work it out, but you can configure it to be whatever you want too.

Answer (score -1):

Try the singular_name 'Testimonial'.

```
http://localhost:8080/boltCMS/Testimonial/1
```

Comment: Not a proper way to post your comment, whether you have sufficient reputation or not.